# Making Windows10 Bootable Media For Mid2012 MacBook Air

Tags: macos, terminal, windows-10, osx-mountain-lion

So I have Macbook Air with this Configuration

Model Identifier:11-inch, Mid 2012 MacBookAir 5,1

Processor  1.7 GHz Intel Core i5

Memory  4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Graphics  Intel HD Graphics 4000 512 MB

Software  OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion)

So the problem obviously is OS X Mountain Lion because I can't run newer apps and chrome is tripping out asking me to update it therefore:

I want to install Windows10 on it
so I tried Windows10 usb with Exfat format but older generation of Mac doesn't support booting with Exfat

So now I want to create usb out of fat32 format but it does't support file transfer larger then 4GB.
Now the actual iso is 6.22 GB and I was able copy all the iso files to the usb accept this one install.wim which is 5.34GB however after few ours search I found this post https://superuser.com/questions/362177/how-to-split-big-files-on-mac/471564 and the person in that post is also pointing out to this post http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060125023540821
in these posts the code is given to split the file in to smaller chunks `split -b YOUR_EXPECTED_SIZES YOUR_FILE_NAME PATTERN_NAME_AS_OUTPUT`
and this code to recover the files after being transferd to the usb `cat SPITED_FILES_AS_LIST > NEW_FILE`  but I don't know how to navigate the code to the Downloads folder where I have put the install.wim file to split it
here is the picture [install.wim in downloads folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8tlD.png)
and here it is in the windows iso file [install.wim file in Windows10 iso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKn52.png)
I am just making this one up for correction for example `split -b 2024m Volumes/Downloads/"install.wim" "install.wim."`

please let me know if somebody knows how to write this code because I didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a windows install media externally won't work as macOS wont boot from any other os. Try using patchers from authentic sources, you can follow the instructions in https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/install-macos-old-mac-3654960/ or just search for "how to get <macOS version of your choice <>> on older Macs" and use those patchers.

For the windows 10 problem, if you are set on using windows, try bootcamp. Most Macs have an application called boot camp assistant preinstalled, or you could just download bootcamp online and then install windows 10. Use this site for help in the process : https://www.imore.com/how-install-windows-your-mac-boot-camp

Just reiterating that external boot drives WILL NOT WORK. This is due to macOS being made by Apple, and you know how Apple is, its kinda expected.

Good luck!

Edit : after re-reading the question I realised I did not answer your question but you could just skip the code part and do this. Its easier cuz its meant to be used by people who are not exactly tech savvy and its extremely simple